# Accessing object from another class of the same parent

Tags: java, class, dart, object, oop

I was transfering an objected oriented code which was written previously on JAVA to dart to test it visually on my device through flutter framework. 
I have a class called **Person** that has two child classes which are **SuperPerson**(That has two child classes which are **SuperHero** and **Villian** and has an *Attack* Method) and **Civil**. and i made a method for the **SuperHero** class which is called *protect* that is targeted to protect objects from the **Civil** class.

 
 Right now, i'm trying to make that when the **Villian** call the *Attack* method several times on a **SuperHero**'s object to the point where that object's health get to Zero, it makes the **SuperHero** object no longer protecting the **Civil**. and I'm not really sure on how to access **Civil**'s object so that i can make them unprotected by the **SuperHero** object after death.

**Person Class**

```
class Person {
 //civil side
   String protector = '';
   bool protection = false;
  //hero side
   String protectedTargetName = '';
   bool protecting = false;

  //setters
    //Civil side
      String setProtector(String protector) {
        return this.protector = protector;
      }
    
      bool setCivilProtection(bool protection) {
        return this.protection = protection;
      }
    
    //Hero Side
      String setProtectedTargetName(String protectedTargetName) {
        return this.protectedTargetName = protectedTargetName;
      }
    
      bool setHeroProtection(bool protecting) {
        return this.protecting = protecting;
      }

    //getters
    //civil side
      String getProtector() {
        return protector;
      }
    
      bool isProtected() {
        return protection;
      }
    
    //hero side
      String getProtectedTargetName() {
        return protectedTargetName;
      }
    
      bool isProtecting() {
        return protecting;
      }
  }
```

**SuperHero Class**

```
class SuperHero extends SuperPerson
{      
  SuperHero(String n, int a, String s, String p) : super(n, a, s, p) {
        setProtectedTargetName('none');
        setHeroProtection(false);
      }

 void toProtect(Person target, BuildContext context) {
    String tName = target.getName();
    String pName = getName();
    setProtectedTargetName(target.getName());//Hero's side
    setHeroProtection(true);//Hero's side
    target.setCivilProtection(true);//Civil's side
    target.setProtector(getName());//Civil's side
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      content: Text('$tName is under $pName\'s protection.'),
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  void toUnProtect(Person target, BuildContext context) {
    String tName = target.getName();
    String pName = getName();
    setProtectedTargetName('none');//Hero's side
    setHeroProtection(false);//Hero's side
    target.setCivilProtection(false);//Civil's side
    target.setProtector('none');//Civil's side
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      content: Text('$tName is no longer under $pName\'s protection'),
    );
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
```

**Civil Class**

```
class Civil extends Person {
  //Constructor
  Civil(String n, int a, String s) : super(n, a, s) {
    setProtector('None');
    setCivilProtection(false);
  }
}
```

**Villian Class**:  Here it only remove the protection from the **SuperHero**'s side but there still protection on the **Civil**'s side which i don't know how to access it from here.

```
void attack(Person target, BuildContext context) {
    String tName = target.getName();
    String tPronouns = target.pronouns();
    String tProtector = target.getProtectorName();
    if (!(target.isProtected())) {
      super.attack(target, context);
      if (target.isProtecting()) {
        if (target.getHealth() == 0) {
          final snackBar = SnackBar(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            content:
                Text('$tName is no longer under $tProtector\'s protection'),
          );
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
          //Hero side
          target.setProtectedName('none');
          target.setHeroProtection(false);
          //Supposed to be Civil side but idk how to do it properly
          setCivilProtection(false);
          setProtectorName('none');
        }
      }
    } else {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        content: Text(
            'You can\'t attack $tName, $tPronouns is already under $tProtector\'s protection'),
      );
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    }
  }
```

**UPFATE** 
Declaring a variable which is responsible for storing the protected **Civil** worked fine and without errors in Java. however, when i tried to transfer it to dart i recieved an error since that i'm not quite familiar with dart.

**Person class**

```
Person protectedPerson; //Error at this line

  Person getProtectedPerson() {
    return protectedPerson;
  }

  Person setProtectedPerson(Person protectedPerson) {
    return this.protectedPerson = protectedPerson;
  }
```

The error:

```
    Non-nullable instance field 'protectedPerson' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it 'late'.
```

In addition to recieving another error when i'm trying to unprotect the **Civil**.
I don't know if there's any additional way to make this function accepts Null value.

```
setProtectedPerson(null);
```

The error:

```
The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Person'.
```

**UPDATE - Solution**

adding question mark after the type helped to solve all the errors.

```
Person? protectedPerson;

  Person? getProtectedPerson() {
    return protectedPerson;
  }

  Person? setProtectedPerson(Person? protectedPerson) {
    return this.protectedPerson = protectedPerson;
  }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can a SuperHero protect multiple Civils? If so, store a list of Civils that the SuperHero is currently protecting (`List<Civil>`) as an attribute. Whenever a SuperHero dies, remove the protector of all of the members of the list of the corresponding SuperHero.

```
List<Civil> protectedCivils;

// Whenever you want to remove all of the SuperHero's (target) protection of its Civils.
target.removeProtectedCivils();

// What the method would look like
void removeProtectedCivils() {
   for(Civil civil : protectedCivils) civil.removeProtection();
}
```

Otherwise, if the SuperHero can only protect one Civil, store the currently protected Civil as an attribute in SuperHero and then you can access it whenever you want to remove the protection relationship. Overall, your code looks could be improved by just referencing the objects in question instead of using Strings and Booleans.

Comment: It worked fine in JAVA when i made variable that store the protected Civil so that can be accessed by the SuperHero. However, its comes when i try to transfer it to dart i recieve couple of errors that i have no clue how to fix them. You can check my edited post for further clarification.

Comment: @maghraby Sorry I have never touched Dart so I can't help you with that, but I'm pretty certain there has to be a way to store references to your custom classes in Dart instead of using strings.

Comment: I just figured out how to solve these errors. Thank you anyway.